# Looping through events in python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have developed a small program that checks for double booking in google calendar. My problem is if I chose to check the 10 July, it will check for the 10 AND for the 11.

This is the problematic part of the code:

```py
for i in range(3):
    # Gets the start and end times and strips them so that days can be added 
    # and to check if the current day is a weekend
    startStrip = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    endStrip = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    dayOfWeek = startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    # les bons formats
    currentStart = str(startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")
    currentEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")
    calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).replace(" ", "T")

    # If the current day is a weekend, add 2 days
    if dayOfWeek.weekday() > 4:
        currentStart = str(startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 2)).replace(" ", "T")
        currentEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 2)).replace(" ", "T")
        calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 3)).replace(" ", "T")
    else:
        print("Looking...")

    # Call the Calendar API
    # Finds the event for the current day
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=currentStart + "-00:00",
                                          maxResults=30, timeMax=calendarEnd + "-00:00",
                                          singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    currentEmployees = []
    for event in events:
        currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])
```

the problem here, is `calendarEnd`. The `calendarEnd` = end of appointment + 1.

so whenever I loop to check all events, and to see if the employees name is registered in the day, it will not only check for the 10th july but for the 11 also. And this causes problems.

If I remove the ''+1'' and only keep this like that :

`calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")`

It won't even load the currentEmployees list correctly. For some reason, in this list,  It will NEVER add the event that is over 1PM and only add the events that starts in the morning.

The desired output should be, if I want to add an event for the 10 July, the code should add in `currentEmployees[]` all the summary events of the 10 july ONLY.

**EDIT**:

As you can see in this example, it will return everyone from the 16th july, and the 2 other employees that are booked the 17th july EXCEPT the one that is 1pm!

[image]

Comment: So when you make the API call it returns a list? And when you ask for one day it always returns the next day as well within that list?

Comment: @EdwinCruz yes, exactly.

Comment: Since it always returns all the elements you ask for plus one more and you not simply remove the last element from the list it returns?

Comment: @EdwinCruz I updated my question "EDIT". Sometimes, it's more than 1 element that gets added, i dont know how much.. it all depends on when they start their appointment.. you can see in the added picture

Comment: Hi there @JessicaZveknia! [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects hold a defined timespan. In your case, when the script adds one full day to the `calendarEnd` variable, your request *spill* over the following day. For example, if your `startStrip` is set to 10 am, then `calendarEnd` will end at 10 am the following day. To prevent this to be the origin of the issue, could you please share a version of your code that uses definite timestamps instead of timespans?

Comment: Hey @Jacques-GuzelHeron ! Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I'm not sure how to use definite timestamps instead of timespans... calendarEnd should ALWAYS be 23:59:59 of the end date. Let's say I want to add 27th June 9am to 11am, well, calendarEnd should be 27 june 23:59:59. how do i do that? Can I do it in a scuffed way? Since calendarEnd is a string, How can I replace the time at the end individually to get 23:59:59? IF i make it a character or list then convert it back to a string.. I don't even know what I'm saying. I don't know how to do it! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this :

`timeMin=currentStart + "-00:00",`

I had to do this to convert in EDT time:

`timeMin=currentStart + "-04:00",`

*I feel so dumb.*

**I also had to remove**  `(days=i + 1)` in :

`calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).replace(" ", "T")`

to become:

`calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")`

Since the + 1 added an extra day